# NestedScrollView fills full screen

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

This is the original layout in my Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp.MyActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/content_my_activity"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It looks okay:

[image]

The content layout file contains a TableLayout.

As the content can be long, I added a NestedScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp.MyActivity">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/content_my_activity"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now the layout *fills the entire screen* and the title is ***behind the AppBar***:

[image]

What should I modify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nested scroll view is told to match the parent in width and height, and normally the ActionBar reserves room and pushes content down accordingly, but the new AppBarLayout matched with a ToolBar doesn't do this. This means the other layouts need to be told of the AppBarLayout's existance.

Try to add this to your NestedScrollView

```
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, adding that attribute solved the issue. This should be mentioned more clearly in the developer guidelines :)